# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function

Tags: jquery

Hi I Know this has been asked before but no answer on here seems to help me.

I have this block of JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.play-icon-hover').hover(function() {
         $('.cms-model-banner-overlay').addClass('.cms-model-banner-overlay-active');
        }, function() {
         $('.cms-model-banner-overlay').removeClass('.cms-model-banner-overlay-active');
    });
});
```

And I seem to be getting this error but I have no idea why?

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function
```

Thanks

Comment: First check: Have you added and loaded jQuery?

Comment: Okay, can you please put the whole HTML, CSS, JavaScript along with this question?

Comment: Does `jQuery(document).ready(...)` works?

Comment: Yes, as Karl said, can you try with `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Comment: Here is the site I am getting the error on and it looks fine to me: http://dev.drivencarsales.co.uk/ssangyong-tivoli

Can you notice anything?

Comment: I've closed as duplicate with a question related to Wordpress since your problem is exactly the same. Just replace "Wordpress" for "whatever CMS you're using".

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Yes, I was about to say, it is something else, but that doesn't answer his question, but that question answers this question. Funny, but true. `:)`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are using `Prototype.js` as well as `jQuery.js`. If you wanna use jQuery, it is better to encapsulate your code inside an IIFE like this:

```
(function ($) {
  // jQuery code using $
})(jQuery);
```

So the solution for your issue is either you change `$` to jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.play-icon-hover').hover(function() {
    jQuery('.cms-model-banner-overlay').addClass('.cms-model-banner-overlay-active');
  }, function() {
    jQuery('.cms-model-banner-overlay').removeClass('.cms-model-banner-overlay-active');
  });
});
```

Or, use a IIFE:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.play-icon-hover').hover(function() {
      $('.cms-model-banner-overlay').addClass('.cms-model-banner-overlay-active');
    }, function() {
      $('.cms-model-banner-overlay').removeClass('.cms-model-banner-overlay-active');
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks heaps sir. Just wondering: how did you find that `Prototype.js` was the culprit? I'm asking because I had this problem building a custom page on FreshDesk [something is creating the same issue, which I solved already with your excellent answer]

Comment: @Antonino Sorry mate, it's been more than 5 years. Lemme try to recollect my memories. Prototype and jQuery (and many other tools) use `$` as their starting point, so the confusion caused in the WordPress times where they all conflict with each other. I guess that was the fact I remember. And thanks! 

Comment: ok, no worries. I saw it was an "old" answer but I gave it a try. Thanks anyway for the details and have a good day!

Comment: @Antonino You too! 