# If i use jQuery(document).ready(function(){ ... my code}) = undifined function

Tags: javascript, jquery, advanced-custom-fields, owl-carousel, gutenberg-blocks

I'm trying to use owl carousel in a wordpress ACF custom block.

owl carousel works if I don't put `jQuery(document).ready` in my script.
But if I have `jQuery(document).ready`, the console tells me "jQuery (...). OwlCarousel is not a function".

Then i don't know if there is link beetwen both but i have thumbnail gallery to click for launch slider on specific image and that code :

```
jQuery('.single_image_gallery').click(function(){
    mySlide = parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('data-slide'));
    jQuery(mySlider).trigger("to.owl.carousel", [mySlide, 1,true])  
})
```

not working at all.

i know there is problem with jQuery migrate for wp 5.5 but I tried with the plugin "Enable jQuery Migrate Helper" and the result is the same....

Comment: what errors are you getting with `jQuery(document).ready`? you would definitely want it. could try something like IIFE passing in jquery, `(function($){ })(jQuery)`

Comment: how is your script enqued? did you add owl as a dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this.. Sometimes plugins can interfere with jQuery

```
jQuery(function($) {
// then use it like this
 $('.single_image_gallery').click(function(){
   mySlide = parseInt($(this).attr('data-slide'));
   $(mySlider).trigger("to.owl.carousel", [mySlide, 1,true])  
 });  
});
```

This way you import $ locally and it should prevent it from interfering with other global scripts or plugins

Comment: Thx you very much ! you're my hero.... and this post as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056230/uncaught-typeerror-ready-is-not-a-function