# JQuery: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).ready(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I know this question has been asked so many times. And it still isn't working out for me.
The answers I've tried so far:

- [TypeError: jQuery(…).ready(…) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755397/typeerror-jquery-ready-is-not-a-function/21755493)
- [$ is not a function when calling jQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function)
- [Uncaught TypeError: $(…).ready is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056230/uncaught-typeerror-ready-is-not-a-function)
- [TypeError: jQuery(…).ready(…) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755397/typeerror-jquery-ready-is-not-a-function/21755501)

And so on. So, here's my code.

**Header.php**

```js
// It used to be in footer. For development purpose now it's in header and can't be moved. The whole application crashes otherwise.
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Form.php**

```js
if (typeof $ == 'undefined') {
    var $ = jQuery;
  }

function submitMe() {
  $('form').submit(); //  This is working fine.

  $('#pendingTable').pendingSubmit();
}

$(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(e) {

    //prevent Default functionality
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post(
      form_ajax_url,
      $(this).serialize(),
      function(response) {
        if (response.flg == 1) {
          $('#id').val(response.id);
        }

        alert(response.msg);
      },
      'json');

  });

});
/* The following function shows uncaught type error and says: $('#pendingTable').pendingSubmit() is not a function. */
$(function() {
  $('#pendingTable').pendingSubmit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Custom code goes here
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title_bar">
  <button class="btn btn-primary bgorange" type="button" onclick="submitMe()">Save</button>
</div>
```

So, I tried this again with the 'pendingSubmit()' function.

```js
(function($) {
  $('#pendingTable').pendingSubmit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Custom code goes here.
  });
})(jQuery);
```

I've also tried 'anonymous function' and moving the whole function inside a closure function. What am I doing wrong? Will you please help me?

Comment: What is `pendingSubmit`? Is it a custom function ?

Comment: Yes. `pendingSubmit()` function has it's specific purpose.

Comment: Can you show us declaration of pendingSubmit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you are trying to do is define a `.pendingSubmit` function in jQuery, in which case you need to follow jquery methods to define a custom function of your own.

Check out #3 here https://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-declare-functions-jquery/

```js
$.fn.extend({
    pendingSubmit: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //whatever other stuff you wanted to add in this function 
    }
});
//Now this should work
$('#pendingTable').pendingSubmit();
```

Define your function at the top of your script just to be safe since JavaScript is read top to bottom